# Saving Login with Playwright

Tags: python, playwright

I'm trying to save my login with playwright, I've read the documentation and tried to implement it into my code but I am still getting errors

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False, slow_mo=50)
    page = context.new_page()
    page.fill("input#input-username", "demo")
    page.fill("input#input-password", "demo")
    page.click("button[type=submit]")
    context = browser.new_context(storage_state="website1.json")
    storage = context.storage_state(path="website1.json")
```

```
page = context.new_page()
```

NameError: name 'context' is not defined

Super confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem:

> `context.new_page()` calls before variable declaration(`context = ...`)

Should works fine:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False, slow_mo=50)
    context = browser.new_context(storage_state="website1.json")
    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto('https://demo.opencart.com/admin')
    page.fill("input#input-username", "demo")
    page.fill("input#input-password", "demo")
    page.click("button[type=submit]")
```

Also you can use [Persistent authentication](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/auth#persistent-authentication):

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    user_data_dir = 'FULL_PATH_TO_BROWSER_PROFILE'
    browser = p.chromium.launch_persistent_context(user_data_dir, headless=False)
    # login only 1 time...
```

JFYI: `opencart` uses `user_token` in `GET` parameters and validates it. `playwright`(`storage_state`, `user_data_dir` etc) should works fine. Example:

```
# run docker container with playwright
docker rm -fv example && docker run --name example -it mcr.microsoft.com/playwright/python:v1.27.1-focal bash
# create empty state
echo {} >> /tmp/state.json
# run python in interactive mode
python
# Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun 22 2022, 20:18:18) 
# [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
# Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Paste the next script:

```
from time import sleep
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    # login
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    context = browser.new_context(storage_state='/tmp/state.json')
    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto('https://demo.opencart.com/admin')
    page.fill('input#input-username', 'demo')
    page.fill('input#input-password', 'demo')
    page.click('button[type=submit]')
    sleep(5)  # just wait for redirect - you can wait for a element...
    page.context.storage_state(path='/tmp/state.json')
    page.screenshot(path='/tmp/after_state_init.png')
    # parse user_token for GET requests
    parsed_url = parse_qs(page.url)
    user_token = parsed_url['user_token'][0]
    print(f'user token {user_token}')
    page.close()
    browser.close()


with sync_playwright() as p:
    # open admin dashboard without login... 
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    context = browser.new_context()
    page = browser.new_page(storage_state='/tmp/state.json')
    page.goto(f'https://demo.opencart.com/admin/index.php?route=common/dashboard&user_token={user_token}')
    sleep(5)
    page.screenshot(path='/tmp/open_using_saved_state.png')
    page.close()
    browser.close()
```

Now open a new terminal and copy screens from docker container:

```
docker cp example:/tmp/after_state_init.png ./
docker cp example:/tmp/open_using_saved_state.png ./
```

You'll see that they are the same - admin dashboard works without login.